# Access getExternalCacheDir() in a Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I need pass the external cache directory to a post request, I've been unable to find away to call the getExternalCacheDir() method from within the fragment, I can only call it in the Activity.

Is it possible to use this method in a fragment, or is there another solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call `getActivity().getExternalCacheDir()`.

Comment: Is it possible to set this outside of an Activity say in a helper class as a private static String variable?

Comment: @Johntk: I would not recommend that. AFAIK, the value should not change during the lifetime of your process, but I cannot rule that out.